# using terminal command into python code

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, openstreetmap

I have a file named **myosm.osm**. If I run the command

```
 $ ogrinfo myosm.osm
```

then I get the following output:

```
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `myosm.osm'
      using driver `OSM' successful.
1: points (Point)
2: lines (Line String)
3: multilinestrings (Multi Line String)
4: multipolygons (Multi Polygon)
5: other_relations (Geometry Collection)
```

I want to implement this command into my python code and want to get the output in a variable for further use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/):

```
from plumbum.cmd import ogrinfo
output = ogrinfo('myosm.osm')
```

(to install: `pip install plumbum`)

Comment: Hey @shx2, thanks a lot. Your answer worked for me. Can you please help me to run     **$ ogr2ogr outdir myosm.osm points** in the same process, please.

Comment: Try: `from plumbum.cmd import ogr2ogr; output = ogr2ogr['outdir', 'myosm.osm','points']()`